# Gradle Artifactory Plugin - How to auto-deploy spring boot fatjar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, artifactory

I've installed the Gradle Artifactory Plugin in my Spring Boot project and I want to deploy the FatJar produced by the `bootRepackage` task to my Artifactory server. However I can't find a way to achieve it.

Here's my base configuration :

```
artifactory {
    publish {
        contextUrl = "https://my.artifacto.ry/artifactory/"
        repository {
            [...] //Credential
            maven = true
        }
        defaults {
            publications ('mavenJava')
        }
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java // <--- I need to set the Spring Boot
                                 //      task result (fatjar) right there
        }
    }
}
```

I already used this configuration for publishing Jar only and it went straightforward every time. Does anybody knows how to configure it to publish Spring Boot fatjar instead of my classes only?

Comment: Ever find an answer?

Comment: We broke build and artifactoryPublish into two separate gradle invocations in our jenkins file.  this led to remaking the jar without springboot.  One call with build...artifactoryPublish, and no problems.   But that's not quite your problems.  Perhaps you need uploadArchives clause. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. Adding this code to a Gradle project configuration should do:

```
artifactoryPublish {
   dependsOn bootRepackage
}
```

With that, `bootRepackage` is run before `artifactoryPublish`, so the JAR it takes and uploads should be the Spring Boot fat JAR.